Series expansion probably related to a modified Bessel function of the first kind
Recently, I came across the following series expansion
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(s+2k-1)!}{k!(s+k)!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{s+2k}$$
It looks similar to a modified Bessel function of the first kind, but I didn't manage to resum this series in terms of Bessel functions. Mathematica resums it as
$$\frac{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^s \, _2F_1\left(\frac{s}{2},\frac{s+1}{2};s+1;x^2\right)}{s} $$
Does anyone know if it is possible to get an expression for this power series in terms of Bessel functions?
Many thanks in advance.

It's related to an associated Legendre function of the second kind: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_function#Solutions_of_the_differential_equation

The sum is equal to
$$
\frac{1}{s}\left(\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)^s.
$$
I don't think there is any connection with Bessel functions.
